# Add new table to an existing ASP.NET Identity Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created a new ASP.NET MVC in Visual Studio 2015 and used ASP.NET Identity for security-related stuff.

I would like to add a new table in the ASP.NET Identity db using Code First migrations.

I created a "Test" table (Test.cs) and did the ff. Code First migration steps in PMC:

- enable-migrations
- add-migrations "Test"
- update-database

but I'm getting an error: There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in development you can try to delete the database manually and then run again update-database command.

Answer (score 0):

First run an initial migration before adding the table with :

```
Add-Migration Initial -IgnoreChanges
```

Afterwards add your table, add another 'normal' migration and update your database.